# get user by access google oauth2 token

Tags: google-app-engine

I need login user in server side by access token and get their user infomrmations. it is possible ?
Im looks in com.google.appengine.api but Im not find it.
I get acces token in client side using google oauth2 and after send to server.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with calling url to google api.

```
public UserInfo login(String token) {

    String json = getJsonDataFromUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?access_token=" + token);
    UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    try{
        userInfo = gson.fromJson(json, UserInfo.class);
        userInfo.logined = true;
        HttpSession session = getRequest().getSession();
        session.setAttribute("userKey", userInfo.encodedKey);
    }catch (Exception ex){
        log.log(Level.WARNING, ex.getMessage());
        throw ex;
    }
    return userInfo;
}

private String getJsonDataFromUrl(String aurl){
    String json = "";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(aurl);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String line;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          json+=line;
        }
        reader.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
    return json;
}
```